# elastic search ignore_above setting use

Tags: elasticsearch

can anyone please help on one of the doubts regarding the explaination if ignore above that is there in the elastic document 
its mentioned that 
Strings longer than the ignore_above setting will not be indexed or stored. For arrays of strings, ignore_above will be applied for each array element separately and string elements longer than ignore_above will not be indexed or stored.

does this means that if i add data longer then the length then it won't allow to post data in ES

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-above.html#ignore-above

Here is what i have tried

my mapping for index testData(i.e index i created) is as follows

using PUT mapping api i added the following mapping

```
{
"testdata": {
    "mappings": {
        "testdata": {
            "properties": {
                "email": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

i added data which has length i.e around 150kb(by length around 145149)
it allowed to add the data in the email field , i am also able to search data using post search endpoint, should it allow do to that or am i getting this concept wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your setting ignore_above: 256 means if the string length is greater than 256 characters then the document is indexed but that field will not be indexed. If the string length is < 256 characters then the document along with the field will be indexed. Example - String length for text "stackoverflow" is 13 characters. Hope this clarifies.

As per your mapping, the ignore_above setting is applied to the `email.keyword` field.

Comment: @ben556 the point you mentioned id string length is less then 256 then it will be index correct , my point is i added data to a the field which has ignore_above": 256 and i added around 145149 characters that is around 100kb . but i am able to perform POST search and get result on that field , i suppose if the field will not get indexed then it should not allow to be searched correct.

Comment: Ignore_above setting is applied to email.keyword field not email field.

Comment: Saying that the "field will not be indexed" is a bit misleading. The field would be indexed as type `text` when the length is greater than 256 and `keyword` when it is less than 256.

Answer (score 2):

I solve my problem today ,I can't get agg terms value by xx.keyword. My value length is 315.

if string longer than the ignore_above value , xx.keyword will not work for search. But the value can be saved , you can search the doc by other fields.